# How to change the background of Viewbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to change the viewbox background but cannot succeed.
Border backgorund can be changed but I want to change the Bcakground of Viewbox whole.

Comment: Put an element with a Background into the Viewbox, e.g. a Panel.

Comment: What is contained in your Viewbox?